# Is #bluemix approved for sensitive information (SPI, BSI, etc)?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Are bluemix databases, connectors and applications approved for use with sensitive or IBM confidential information (SPI, BSI, etc)?

Comment: Hi Hector. Which services are you planning to use? With that information, a better answer can be provided.

Comment: I'm trying to use sqldb service combined with excel connecting from ODBC. The final goal is a simple data form to be loaded and maintained from excel. The catch is the data is SPI...

Comment: Hector - Please contact me internally on Sametime.